# How to enable nodeIntegration on child window

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm working on electron project that must have child window for the app. I set `nodeIntegration: true` for main window and I want to apply that to the child window too, but for some reason I can't. I need to enabling nodeIntegration because I want use that on child window.

To create the child window I used `window.open` function from electron and set nodeIntegration to true but the status is still false on child window.

**Here is my code:**

```
if(content === 'main'){
    let mainSheet = './sheets/main_sheet.html';

    //open in proxy window
    let readerWin   = window.open(mainSheet, '', `
    maxWidth=2048,
    maxHeight=2048,
    width=1920,
    height=1080,
    fullscreenable=true,
    contextIsolation=1,
    nodeIntegration=true,
    frame: false`)
}
```

**This is the error on child window**
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTZ6v.png)

i want to make read and write file system in the child window. When i load another file to the `main_sheet.html` the error above appeared.

this main_sheet.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ....
    <script src="../fileSystem/filesystem.js"></script>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
      .....
  </body>
</html>
```

and filesystem.js file:

```
const fs = require("fs");

let saveBTN = document.getElementById('save-data');

saveBTN.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    fs.writeFile("temp.txt", data, (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log("Successfully Written to File.");
    });
})
```

How to enable nodeIntegration on child window using `window.open` function so i can using read and write in electron ?

Comment: did you try with setting  nodeIntegrationInSubFrames or nodeIntegrationInWorker  to true(cf https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window)?

Comment: i've try to setting nodeIntegration: true on main.js (main process),
how to setting nodeIntegrationInSubFrames?

Comment: @AriefBudiPrasetyo try my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58300341/12167785

Answer (score 2):

> The features string follows the format of standard browser, but each
>   feature has to be a field of BrowserWindow's options.

Try, (**Set contextIsolation to no**)

```
   `maxWidth=2048,
    maxHeight=2048,
    width=1920,
    height=1080,
    fullscreenable=yes,
    contextIsolation=no,
    nodeIntegration=yes,
    frame=no`
```

Refer https://electronjs.org/docs/api/window-open

Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features

Comment: i've tried the code above but the result still same :(
the error still same :(

Comment: @AriefBudiPrasetyo kindly post your error message here

Comment: error message is:
uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTZ6v.png)

Comment: i've add more information to the post. sorry if it makes you confused.

Comment: @AriefBudiPrasetyo Hi, find the updated answer. It's working, I have verified

Comment: all setting options work except for nodeIntegration [error image](https://ibb.co/GsLjjMQ)
the error refers to `const fs = require("fs");` in `filesystem.js`

Comment: @AriefBudiPrasetyo make sure in the main.js- BrowserWindow, you have this,   **webPreferences: { nodeIntegration:true})**

Comment: yup, i have this in main.js
`mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 450, height: 700,
    minWidth: 450, minHeight: 700,
    maxWidth: 2048, maxHeight: 2048,
    fullscreenable: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })`

Comment: @AriefBudiPrasetyo try to verify against https://gist.github.com/sudhakar3697/7d3f9dea4156bf0d449ced0e3bb5600b

Comment: @AriefBudiPrasetyo did you check [https://gist.github.com/sudhakar3697/7d3f9dea4156bf0d449ced0e3bb5600b] out?

Comment: @AriefBudiPrasetyo https://gist.github.com/sudhakar3697/7d3f9dea4156bf0d449ced0e3bb5600b

Comment: ,,
Thank you very much for helping me, you saved my day :)
sorry just reply your comment, the last weekend i'm away from computer,,
Thank you very much